# writing spark df to azure sql server with clustered columnstore index and PK/FK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-database, databricks

Consider the following usecase:I want to write a spark data frame to a dwh stored in a azure sql server db using Microsoft’s Apache Spark SQL Connector. Either with "overwrite" or "append" depending on the usecase.

For dwhs, clustered columnstore indexes are recommended. As I also want primary key constrains to be enforced, Nonclustered indexes on a clustered columnstore index probably would yield the best performance.

How do I create or append to tables with pyspark using this index design?

```
df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .mode("overwrite OR append") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", sqldbuser) \
        .option("password", sqldbpwd)
```

The answer does not have to be purely pyspark based (e.g. can use sqlalchemy). It should just work robustly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best approach would be to insert the dataframe from pyspark into a staging table on Azure SQL server (with overwrite), then use a stored procedure to insert the data into your columnstore index dwh table.

In the stored procedure, use something like that:

```
    insert into dwh_table
    select *
    from stg_table
```

Also, try inserting multiple rows at once so that the columnstore index can compress it efficiently (over 1,048,576 rows).

About nonclusterd index - if you need it as a primary key, to prevent duplicates, then you have no choice but to have it active during load.

If not, try to disable nonclustered indexes before load (in your stored procedure), and enable them after load. Please note that this does not always give you the best performance, you'll have to test it with your workload.

Please refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-data-loading-guidance?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I am trying to abstract things away/wrap in a python load function. My thoughts were: Creating the table based on the cols in the df and their data types (use the same as spark internal mapping to sql server) with CREATE TABLE. Then set a unique contraint on the PK cols. After that create clustered column store index. Then, load with df.write and option "truncate" and batchsize > 1,048,577. Would that work? Is this slow? Would loading to temp heap and then inserting be better albeit an extra step? Would setting the unique constraint not consume unecessary ressources?

Comment: just trying to figure out a blueprint I can use for every table

Comment: Writing to a heap should be faster, and then inserting into columnstore table can use parallelism, which loading directly from DF will not. Regarding Unique constraint, maybe you can do this check in databricks (if you write the entire table each time).